# <em> tag removes css style

Tags: html, css

I am learning HTML and CSS.  Currently I am working on tutorial web pages for my math classes.  I want to be able to style equations with Times New Roman and italicize the variables but not the numbers, so I just added a simple class in CSS to override the default font:

```
.function {
font-family: "Times New Roman", serif;}
```

When I format a paragraph like this, the font displays in Times New Roman just like it should:

```
<p class="function">f (x) = 3x - 12</p>
```

But when I add the `em` tags like this:

```
<p class="function"><em>f</em> (<em>x</em>) = 3<em>x</em> - 12</p>
```

The Times New Roman font is replaced by the main font that I am using for text on the page.  I can add `class="function"` tag inside each of the `em` tags, but that kind of defeats the purpose of styling the paragraph.  Why is the CSS style being overridden when I add the emphasis?

Comment: Do you have somewhere where we can see? It could be a global css affecting your styles

Comment: Please add your code in a Stack Snippet so we can see your HTML and CSS.

Comment: "_if I can improve how I ask questions_" You should add a snippet of relevant code here. From the flagging options - "_Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers._"

Answer (score 1):

You can use this :

`ƒ  402 &fnof;`

402 is a `ASCII code`, and `&fnof;` is for HTML

**EDIT**

CHECK THIS FIDDLE PLEASE :

https://jsfiddle.net/0gf71twp/

Comment: HTML uses Unicode, not ASCII. 402 is the decimal representation of the codepoint.  So, ƒ can be written as `&#402;`

Comment: Ok thanks for that explanation. It work with `&fnof` also

Answer (score 0):

KolaCaine’s answer is a good one, and the best way to go. But to solve the CSS, you probably need to apply the font to the em tag specifically, like this:

```
.function em {
    font-family: “Times New Roman”, serif;
}
```

Comment: That makes sense.  I am just starting to move beyond tutorials and into my own code, so I didn't think about that.  Thanks a ton.